Why are 2 diodes needed instead of 1 when diode-ORing two power supplies?
I see many circuits online of dual power supplies connected in parallel through output diodes on their outputs, to provide redundancy in case the main one fails. Usually the primary supply is an AC-DC adapter and the secondary is a battery backup.
I'm designing a 12 V UPS for my router but am not sure why a diode is needed in series with the primary voltage source.
I understand that the diode in the secondary supply rail is needed to prevent the main 12 V supply feeding into it. In my case, the primary rail is a simple mains-to-12 V DC adapter. I don't see any issue in the battery backup "feeding" back to that if it loses power.
This is my design so far. It's missing some capacitors on the load output. Note that the diode I'll use won't be a 1N4148, that's just the default Circuitlab had when I drew it.

As I understand it, the primary 12 V supply will take priority because the voltage on both sides of the diode will be 12v. With 0 V across the diode, it won't conduct and the main supply will power the load. If the primary 12 V system loses power, then the voltage at that point drops and the diode begins to conduct, allowing the boosted-up backup battery to power the load. With a diode voltage drop of, say, 0.5 V this would give 11.5 V.
In this case it's also "backfeeding" into the main primary supply, but I don't see the danger this causes. I'm wondering if I can skip the diode on the primary voltage source in order to avoid the voltage drop that comes with it.

Yes you can skip this extra diode in series with V1, but then ask yourself this question: what happens if V1 fails as a short-circuit, ie: the V1 output shorts out to GND?

Like Fabio already said, a shorted output is a reasonable fail mode so now your screwed when you need it most. Also, it's good practice even if the main power supply never fails but just becomes unpowered - it will act as a light load to your battery supply. It's mains powered; why care about the trace power loss from the diode anyway? The diode is a dime a dozen and the cheapest insurance that's going to protect your expensive batteries and boost controller.

If you don't know how the primary voltage source is design, don't assume it can handle reverse voltage. The most common failure mode ought to be Vin to the primary source missing (due to a power outage etc) and then you end up in a situation where it has Vin=0V, Vout=12V. Voltage regulators tend to break when that happens.

(And obviously don't use 1N4148 but I take it this is just a "pseudo schematic" and in the real application you'll rather use a Schottky which can also handle the current.)

@Lundin, "And obviously don't use 1N4148 but I take it this is just a "pseudo schematic"". Had you read the question through before posting? OP already clearly stated "Note that the diode I'll use won't be a 1N4148, that's just the default Circuitlab had when I drew it".

@TonyM Yeah but they didn't say what to replace it with. A Schottky is one option, a P MOSFET is another option. In fact a low Rds(on) MOSFET would have many advantages and it's custom to use them over diodes in series with supply voltages.

@Lundin, you've tried to jump somewhere else again: your second comment isn't the point you made in your first comment. Best just to address my comment on your first comment otherwise discussion gets nowhere, rather than leading to improvement and better quality for all.

@TonyM You are assuming I want to "discuss" something with you. I do not. I'm only commenting here for the benefit of the OP so that they may find an appropriate solution to their problem.

@Lundin, truly the last thing I want. Just pointing out your innocent mistake and guiding you to the question text: appears you hadn't read the question, as it already makes your later comment irrelevant. If you've now seen that, delete your comments and I can delete mine.

Thanks for the insight, I did not consider the short-circuit case.
The idea behind skipping it was to reduce the voltage drop, as I don't know if the modem and router will continue to work properly at 11.5V/11.6V(or even higher drop at higher currents). I've seen a few designs use PMOSs but they still seemed to use a diode at the end. I'll look further to see if I can find or design a PMOS-controlled one. One thing I wasn't sure about is if the capacitors on the output will keep the PMOS powered until the 12V rail drops so low, that the router powers off before the battery kicks in.

If you assume the power supply tolerates being back-fed, you might as well assume the boost regulator tolerates being back-fed too, and no diodes are necessary. But this is not the case.
You need two diodes because you can't back-feed voltage/current into a powered off-supply. Or you can, but the power supply may get destroyed.
You seem to assume a powered-off supply somehow disconnects itself from the output and does not care if something else keeps the output at 12V (or 11.5V) when mains input to power supply is off.
While some power supplies may tolerate that, some might even be especially designed for it, but some power supplies will not tolerate it and get damaged.
Some power supplies may even have a mechanism to try discharging the output voltage to have a faster and definite turn-off ramp instead of slowly decaying voltage.
You don't know beforehand if the power supply tolerates being back-fed or not.
Therefore you need to assume it does not handle being back-fed, just like you are assuming your battery powered boost converter does not tolerate being back-fed with 12V.

Short: They are not needed
Longer: If you look at the schematic of most common switching mode supplies there is a already a diode in the output, so backfeeding isn't even that big of an issue.
It's a question of what failure mode you want to protect from and what your primary power source is tolerating.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This is a simplified schematic of a typical buck converter commonly used in many power supplies. What you don't see is the implicit reverse Diode in the MOSFET M1.
So if you feed in Voltage at M1, U1 gets a signal on FB (which could prevent it from stating up again if it just has had a paower failure on the primary side). We're also backfeeding into Vin via the implicit reverse Diode in M1.
It can work, it can be no issue at all. It can be no iddue for a few times or under certein circumstances.
Backfeeding in a power supply is normally not a case that's defined in the datasheet. So the device can do whatever it wants if it happens, it's an undefined state.
So putting in that second diode in (it can be a shottky diode or an "ideal diode" if you don't want the voltage drop) is generally just the safe option.

"What you don't see is the implicit reverse Diode in the MOSFET M1" Wouldn't the body diode of an N channel have its anode against Vout? So how exactly is that one doing you any good? You'd need a P channel with drain against Vin and source against Vout like a reverse polarity protection circuit.

This diode wouldn't do you any good. Maybe I should phrase that differently. This Diode can mess you up badly because it might power the "primary side" of the converter making it want to power up again...

By "Ideal Diode" i assume you mean some MOSFET - but looking online at other similar circuits I haven't found a way that people use this without also using a diode on the output.
